# Vue background url correct asset path

Tags: vue.js

I have created a new vue application,
I want to load an image on a div background.
The following works

```
background: url('~../assets/my_image.png');
```

Does my app uses webpack and vue-loader? I cannot find the modules on package.json.
Why do I need to add the ~? Is this going to work after asset compilation on the dist directory?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Is `assets` inside `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Yes. Your app uses Webpack and several different file loaders. These are all part of the Vue library.

Assuming that you've created an `assets` directory inside your `src` directory the tilde is telling Webpack how to rewrite the file path.

`$ npm run build` will compile everything and add it to the `dist` directory so you can verify how paths are treated.

If you DO NOT want Webpack to process your assets you can add content to the `public` directory which will be copied directly to `dist` and become the root directory on your server or `/`.

Here's Vue's take on the [difference between assets and public](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with vue but I would assume you are using a template similar to react-create app and thus you are asking if you are using babel, webpack or other loaders/packages.

If the case is as I mention above then YES you are using webpack. Would recommend research on how the template is built.

For the tilde association I would think these links might help:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/516702/is-the-tilde-considered-to-be-a-relative-path
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm